# Google heatmap layer

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

I've database contain 1.000.000 coordinates. I've google maps api v3 and node.js to render on google heatmap. Google maps have api: Fusion table to help render on heatmap data from server side

I don't want use fusion table. Any other way to render heatmap data without using fusion table??....

Answer (score 0):

You may create a heatmap without FusionTables, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps

But this will  create the heatmap on clientside, which requires to download the complete data(I guess this would be >20MB) and will take its time to process the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client side Heatmap Layer, but it can only render up to 1000  coordinates.
It is not possible to render all the data without using Fusion Tables at the moment.

> Heatmaps use the Maps API Heatmap layer, so they pull data into the browser before displaying it. This is unlike Fusion Tables feature maps that render map tiles on the server. Because of this, only the first 1,000 rows are mapped.

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1152262